# TouchListView : OnClickListener

Tags: android

Whenever I am setting OnClickListener for TouchListView then DropListener and DragListener are not working.
I downloaded the demo of the CWAC: TouchListView.
So how should I implement the OnClickListener for the TouchListView.
Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do ? Please pu some code or put the link of that project

Answer (score 1):

As i Understand there are 2 ways to solve this problem:
1. You must make only one small area off each item touchable to drag. And user will drag your items if he touch item in this area. You can implement it using x-coordinates of your item.
2. You can implement special mode of work of your listview. You can switch to this mode through menu (or another way) and in this mode all area off item can be touchable to drag but not clickable. After draging you can switch back to usual mode of listview.

PS: I describe my approach to solving the problem. It will be great to see something else.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem.

If you follow the Demo project you can set your OnClickListener on the label in the IconicAdapter. The user can scroll using the ImageView and they can press the label to do whatever you would like them to do.

This solution worked for me.